# PHP DOMDocument, wrap all elements without node with p

Tags: php, html, class, dom, domdocument

I get HTML from an RTE. I manipulate it's content afterwards with the DOMDocument Class.

The Editor sometimes gives me text without an node, eg.:

```
<p>This is some text inside a text-node</p>
This is text without any node and should be wrapped with a text-node
```

Is it possible using the DOMDocument to wrap this text with a text-node?

I'm using the following code inside a function:

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($MY_HTML);

    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

    foreach ($xpath->query('//p') as $k => $paragraph) {
        $paragraph->setAttribute('class', $paragraph->getAttribute('class') . ' bodytext');
    }

    $body = $xpath->query('/html/body');
    return preg_replace('/^<body>|<\/body>$/', '', $dom->saveXml($body->item(0)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is technically already inside a ["text node"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Text), but this will wrap all unwrapped text nodes with paragraph nodes:

```
<?php

$html = <<<'END'
<div>
    <p>This is some text inside a text-node</p>
    This is text without any node and should be wrapped with a text-node
</div>
END;

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//text()[not(ancestor::p)][normalize-space()]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $p = $doc->createElement('p', htmlspecialchars(trim($node->textContent)));
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($p, $node);
}

print $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);

// <div>
//   <p>This is some text inside a text-node</p>
// <p>This is text without any node and should be wrapped with a text-node</p>
// </div>
```

The key is to select all the non-empty text nodes without `p` ancestors, using the `//text()[not(ancestor::p)][normalize-space()]` XPath query.